Lower bound for distance between roots of polynomial equations
Consider a set of multivariate polynomial equations, i.e. $f_i(x_1, \dots, x_n)=0$ for $i=1,\dots,m$ with $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f_i$ a polynomial. Assume the set of solutions of these equations is zero-dimensional. We can denote all equations by the function $f: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$, the set of solutions corresponds to the set of roots of $f$.
I am now interested in a lower bound for the distance $||\vec{x}-\vec{y}||_2$ for any pair of roots $\vec{x},\vec{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (ie. $f(\vec{x})=f(\vec{y})=0, \vec{x}\neq\vec{y}$).
I am so far aware of

the bound resulting from Smale's $\alpha$-theory $\left(||\vec{x}-\vec{y}||\geq \frac{5-\sqrt{17}}{4 \sup_{k\geq 2}||Df(\vec{x})^{-1} D^kf(\vec{x}) 1/k!||^{1/k-1}}\right)$, which however in my case is hard to argue about, as the operator norm of the inverse of the Jacobian is unclear.
the Mignotte bound (and more modern improvements thereupon, see e.g. 'The DMM Bound: Multivariate (Aggregate) Separation Bounds' (2010), I. Emiris, B. Mourrain and E. Tsigaridas), which to my understanding are however exponentially small in the number of unknowns (and thus not tight enough for my application).
(the Canny gap theorem, which however to my understanding is strictly worse than the above.)

What other results or strategies might I use to lower bound the distance of pairs of roots? In case it helps, I would be especially interested in the special case where $n=m+1$, the degree of all polynomials is $2$ and an asymptotic scaling with $m$ would already be helpful.
